# How to display an issue title in markdown

Tags: gitlab

We create release notes based on the issue number and title.
We can use `#123` to get the issue referenced in the merge request description (that we then copy paste as the release notes).
However, what I'd like is to get the title of these issues as well.

Is there a markdown sequence or another way to get the title of the issues based on the issue number?

If there's a tool that parses the commits of the merge request and creates some output of issue numbers & titles that would be an acceptable solution as well.

Cheers.

Comment: Hmmmm. There is no builtin way and no tool that I know of that does this other than to write the title/link yourself in markdown. The closest thing I can think of to this would be documentation tools like mkdocs or sphinx where you could build an extension to do this... but it would be geared for built docs, not really for MR descriptions, comments or anything like that. Alternatively, you could probably write a tampermonkey/greasemonkey script to get the behavior you want by swapping the link `title` attribute with its text, but only _you_ (or others with the script) would see it of course.

Answer (score 4):

With [GitLab 14.6](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2021/12/22/gitlab-14-6-released/#render-the-title-of-a-referenced-issue-within-markdown) (December 2021), you have another (new) option:

> ### Render the title of a referenced issue within markdown
>
> When referencing issues, epics, or merge requests within markdown fields, there was previously no way to surface and display additional context other than the ID.
>
> You can now **append `+` to an issue, epic, or merge request reference to render the title**.
>
> [image: https://about.gitlab.com/images/14_6/render_the_title_of_a_referenced_issue_within_markdown.gif -- Render the title of a referenced issue within markdown]
>
> See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/markdown.html#show-the-issue-merge-request-or-epic-title-in-the-reference) and [Issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/15694).

Answer (score 3):

As I mentioned in the comments, I don't know of any existing tool or functionality for this.

### Generate markdown

The closest thing for this may be to use a document generation tool like mkdocs or sphinx to generate markdown using a custom plugin. For example, a modified version of the [mkdocs-gitlab-plugin](https://gitlab.inria.fr/vidjil/mkdocs-gitlab-plugin) could use the API to retrieve the title and render the title in the doc.

### Tampermonkey

To get the effect you're looking for locally, a tampermonkey script can  do this as well. However, this will only be a local effect.

```js
// ==UserScript==
// @name         GitLab Ref changes
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      0.1.0
// @description  Change issue references hyperlinks from #123 to their title
// @author       Spencer Phillip Young
// @match        https://gitlab.com/*
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==

(function() {
    'use strict';

    function gitlabRef() {
        const anchorElementList = Array.from(document.getElementsByTagName('a'));
        anchorElementList.forEach(function(elem) {
            if (elem.getAttribute('data-reference-type') == 'issue') {
                if (elem.getAttribute('title')) {
                    elem.innerHTML = elem.getAttribute('title');
                }
            }
        });
        setTimeout(() => {
            gitlabRef();
        }, 2000)
    }

    setTimeout(() => {
        gitlabRef();
    }, 1000)
})();
```

Before:

[image: Before script]

After:
[image: After script]

Notice the link for `#340125` changed to its current title: `Usage quotas pagination jumps to "seats" page`

Though, in principle a more intelligent monkey could probably make a tamper script that makes this change when *authoring* merge requests or other markdown. So, as long as *you* (or someone who also has such a script) authors your release notes, everyone will get the benefit of it.

### Webhook to alter MR description

Last idea may be to have a webhook respond to MR create events and rewrite `#123` to `[issue title](link to issue)` in the description.